# Build failed while I was trying to build the stand alone app with expo and react native

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, expo

I am trying to create a build of a stand alone in react native with expo and my build is failing with following error.

× Build failed
 Android build failed:
Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" (https://expo.dev/accounts/rajhans21/projects/qrcodeapp/builds/fbf491ac-d226-4ebf-ab02-72a9aa48748f#run-gradlew) phase for more information.

√ Uploaded to EAS 1s
× Build failed
Build details: https://expo.dev/accounts/rajhans21/projects/qrcodeapp/builds/28aac8f3-fcd5-4a34-892e-66c121de43b6
 Android build failed:nfiguration: Build Credentials KBEV-y960R (default)
Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" (https://expo.dev/accounts/rajhans21/projects/qrcodeapp/builds/28aac8f3-fcd5-4a34-892e-66c121de43b6#run-gradlew) phase for more information.

Can anyone help me resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

- The error message you're seeing indicates that the Android build failed due to an unknown error. This could be caused by several reasons, such as incorrect configuration, missing dependencies, or issues with the Gradle build system.
- Android internal distribution build fail for sdk45 #17253 : https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/17253
- Internal distribution - Learn how EAS Build provides shareable URLs for your builds with your team for internal distribution : https://docs.expo.dev/build/internal-distribution/
- expo build:android [Standalone build failed!] #549 : https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/549
- React Native Android Standalone Build Failed, iOS successful : https://forums.expo.dev/t/react-native-android-standalone-build-failed-ios-successful/19827
- Automating Standalone Expo App Builds and Deployments with Fastlane and Expo CLI : https://blog.expo.dev/automating-standalone-expo-app-builds-and-deployments-with-fastlane-exp-and-exptool-9b2f5ad0a2cd